# Creating instances by static field

Tags: java, static

I have the following two classes:

```
public class A{
    private String s;
    public A(String s){
        this.s = s;
    }
}

public class B{
    private static final String STR = "String";

    public void doAction(){
        A a = new A(STR); //Does it look really wierd?
    }
}
```

I've never passed the static final field as a constructor parameter, so can it lead to potential bugs? Should we avoid it or we can do that if it seems concise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've never passed the static final field as a constructor parameter, so can it lead to potential bugs?

This cannot lead to a bug, because `doAction` is an instance method. All static fields with initializers will be initialized *before* the first instance method is called, so you are safe.

> Should we avoid it or we can do that if it seems concise?

Using a static final field, which is effectively a `String` constant, inside an instance method, is а perfectly valid choice.

Comment: So, it's true for any other immutable static variables, right?

Comment: @user3663882 All static variables with initializers will be initialized before your instance methods are called. This includes mutable static variables, although using mutable static variables is usually discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't worry if the field is immutable (like in your case: `String` is immutable data structure). With mutable objects (for example *arrays*) you should consider that all changes to this field in one object will be visible to other objects with the same field whether it is static or not. These code doesn't look weird.

Answer (score 0):

String is a reference type, but it works like a primitive type sometimes. If you use a String object as an argument, it will be copied, like other primitive variables. I don't understand the reason you pass a class variable as an argument of other object. But it will not occur any problem caused by sharing of an attribute between objects of this class.

Comment: "If you use a String object as an argument, it will be copied, like other primitive variables." The value of the variable is copied in *all* cases, whether with classes or primitives. But with classes (and interfaces) the value is a reference, that's all... and that's just as true for String as anything else.

Comment: @JonSkeet __The value of the variable is copied in all cases__ Do you mean for Strings?

Comment: I mean in *all cases*. The value of the argument becomes the initial value of the parameter. That's how arguments are passed in Java, for all types, always. But you need to understand that the value of a reference-type expression is a reference, not an object. Again, nothing special about String there.